# pull master into new branch show you the conflicts

Tags: git

How do I pull master into the current branch I am working on, and see the conflicts?

Also, should I merge or rebase, not sure which of the two is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you have to pull into the current branch? sounds like trouble.

how about you get the latest master, and then just compare the differences? that way you don't merge without knowing what you're getting into.

in this case:

```
# in your master branch do
git pull origin master
```

switch to the feature branch you're working on:

```
git checkout your_branch_name
```

now that you're in your new branch you can see the differences (green being what you've added, assuming color is on too)

```
git diff master
```

of course you can see a diff from master without doing the checkout. So in that case, you pull origin master and then do a diff:

```
# in master
git pull origin master

# now do a diff while still in master
git diff your_new_feature_branch
```

Comment: I get "error: you need to resolve your current index first" when I try to checkout master, what does this mean?

Comment: probably cause you have a change. `git status` to check. If there's a change you can add it `git add .` and `git commit -m "some comment`, and then you can `checkout`

Comment: if you don't want the change you can just checkout the file `git checkout some_file_you_dont_want.rb`

Answer (score 2):

First pull all the branches from the remote

```
git pull origin
```

After you do this, all the branches will have been pulled(including master).

Now you want to merge master into your current branch so you do:

```
git merge master
```

If it resolved any conflicts automatically then you're *done*.

If it says it **didn't** merge the changes automatically then you need to resolve the conflict.

To resolve the conflict edit your ~/.gitconfig and add

```
[merge]
    tool = meld
```

Now install the meld diff tool(for example on Ubuntu you just do `sudo aptitude install meld`

You will get a window like this

[image: Meld screenshot]

On the left you'll have your local version. On the right you'll have the remote version.

In the middle is your desired state after the merge. After you choose and pick all the bits from the both sides and put them in the middle, save (CTRL+S) and exit meld. Git will now tell you about the next file you have to merge and you will do the same until you finish the merge.

You can do `git diff` at the end of this to ensure that the merge you've done is correct.

Also run your code to make sure it works as you want it to.

Then you commit `git commit -am "commit_message"` and you push the changes to your branch.

Answer (score 0):

Merging and rebasing both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Advantages of rebase:
  keeps the commit history "cleaner" in that the current head of 'master' will be an ancestor of your current branch.  Sometimes people don't like having common ancestors buried too deeply in the history.  Some places it's policy to always rebase a feature branch onto master before committing.

Disadvantages of rebase:
  Completely rewrites the history of your branch (all the sha1's will be different).  This can cause trouble if you or anyone else has created branches off of your feature branch, and then you try to merge that back in.

A possible good rule of thumb: rebase branches that have not been published widely and thus are not the basis of other branches.